# How do I retrieve data from firebase realtime database and fill it in a table in unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from a table in firebase Realtime database and sort it in a table I have made inside unity. this is how my database structure look like

[image]

and this is what my code looks like

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Unity;

public class ScheduleRetriever : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Table GameObject
    public GameObject table;
    // Prefab for table rows
    public GameObject rowPrefab;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private void Start()
    {
        // Initialize Firebase
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                // Get reference to the "timetable" node
                mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("timetable");
                // Retrieve data from the "timetable" node
                mDatabaseRef.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
                    if (task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                        // Iterate through the children of the snapshot
                        foreach (var idChild in snapshot.Children)
                        {
                            DataSnapshot idSnapshot = idChild.Value as DataSnapshot;
                            //DataSnapshot idSnapshot = idChild.Value as DataSnapshot;
                            Debug.LogError("wut ");
                            // Add the data to the table
                            AddDataToTable(idChild);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Data retrieval failed: " + task.Exception);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    private void AddDataToTable(DataSnapshot idChild)
    {
        // Create a new row
        GameObject newRow = Instantiate(rowPrefab);
        // Set the parent of the new row to the table
        newRow.transform.SetParent(table.transform, false);
        // Get the text components of the new row
        Text[] rowTexts = newRow.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
        // Set the text of the first column to the "fname" value retrieved from Firebase
        rowTexts[0].text = idChild.Child("fname").Value.ToString();
        // Set the text of the second column to the "monday" value retrieved from Firebase
        rowTexts[1].text = idChild.Child("monday").Value.ToString();
        // Set the text of the third column to the "tuesday" value retrieved from Firebase
        rowTexts[2].text = idChild.Child("tuesday").Value.ToString();
        // Set the text of the fourth column to the "wednesday" value retrieved from Firebase
        rowTexts[3].text = idChild.Child("wednesday").Value.ToString();
        // Set the text of the fifth column to the "thursday" value retrieved from Firebase
        rowTexts[4].text = idChild.Child("thursday").Value.ToString();
        // Set the text of the sixth column to the "friday" value retrieved from Firebase
        rowTexts[5].text = idChild.Child("friday").Value.ToString();
    }

}
```

can anyone help check my code on why the table in unity wouldn't be filled when I run the scene.
and did I code the reference to each node correctly.
thank you!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `ContinueWith` by [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension)

Most of Unity API isn't thread save and can only be used by the Unity main UI thread => you will either get a warning/error in the console or it might get eaten by the task.

As the name says  `ContinueWithOnMainThread` makes sure you are on the Unity main thread when instantiating, setting the texts etc

---

besides that hit <kbd>CTRL + S</kbd> it seems you have unsaved changes there (= yellow lines) ^^

Comment: i have changed it to ContinueWithOnMainThread but it give an error cs1061 which i think means that this firebase sdk doex not include it, adding "using Firebase.Extensions.TaskExtension;" (based on documentation) also give an error. I am sorry if i misunderstood something because this is my first time using firebase in unity.

Comment: if you are using assembly definitions you might need to add an additional reference

Comment: thank you! that is right, sorry again for providing the code in image, I have changed it to code snippet.